# FreeCAD to design moving parts

Tags: 3d-design, mechanics, freecad

I am trying to create a mechanism with moving parts, and would like to see how it works (whether it even works) before printing it.

For example, there's a servo with a bracket, and I would like to see how far can the bracket move before colliding with other objects.

[image]

Unfortunately I cannot find any information on how to set pivot points and rotate objects around these points in FreeCAD. Is this even possible?

Comment: If the user manual doesn't mention it, it's probably not a feature available in FreeCAD.  You may have to consider some more powerful (not free) tool.

Comment: Fusian 360 is free for most use cases and includes moving joints as well as animations of those joints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

freeCad has a draft rotate function in **DRAFT workbench**:

1. Select an object;
2. Press the Draft Rotate button, then;
3. Click to set the rotating point and rotate.

You will get used to that after a few trails.

There is a [step by step guide](https://www.freecadweb.org/wiki/Draft_Rotate) on freeCad site.

There is also a [short demo of the function here](https://youtu.be/5KDEf16MNc0).

Comment: Because... links die, but content typed in here will be archived and searchable.

Comment: I suppose that's as far as I can get with FreeCAD... Not as comfortable as in Blender, but kinda solves the task :

Comment: The link says that three different clicks are required (center point, reference point and rotation point - 5 steps in all). Whilst you do give the main overview, I think that (maybe in this case), a full reproduction of the five steps could be more useful :-) Admittedly, the video may be harder to explain in text (but it probably is [doable](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6798/how-do-you-calibrate-a-delta-robot-3d-printer/6800#6800))

Answer (score 2):

I would also like to take a look at the A2plus Workbench (Freecad Addon). There you can define constraints which can help with this problem. As far as I know, parts cannot be moved with the mouse pointer, but angle parameters can be entered.

https://freecadweb.org/wiki/A2plus_Workbench