# Delta Printer: After Calibration X and Y Axis are slightly different

Tags: marlin, calibration, troubleshooting, delta, axis

I noticed that my x axis is slightly longer than my y axis (~0.6%) if I print an object. What parameter in Marlin can be tuned to correct such issues? The rod length parameter seems to rather influence the overall scaling of the object. The other parameters such as Txyz and Exyz influence the flatness according to the bed. I noticed, on the firmware of the Duet there is a gcode command for this particular issue, which I haven't found in Marlin yet.

Comment: I have the feeling (after reading the config file) it might be DELTA_DIAGONAL_ROD_TRIM_TOWER in https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/bugfix-2.0.x/Marlin/src/config/examples/delta/kossel_xl/Configuration.h#L626

I guess there is no info whether this value can be tuned via menu ..

Comment: This *might* be a duplicate of [Delta printer nozzle not moving square with a perfectly level bed (as if the bed is bent... but it isn't)](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6016/delta-printer-nozzle-not-moving-square-with-a-perfectly-level-bed-as-if-the-bed), but I'm not sure. Is yours a different issue?

Answer (score 1):

I *think* that you probably need to adjust the following two parameters in the Marlin firmware, in `configuration.h`:

- `MANUAL_HOME_Z_POS`, and;
- `DELTA_SMOOTH_ROD_OFFSET`

See [my answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6016/delta-printer-nozzle-not-moving-square-with-a-perfectly-level-bed-as-if-the-bed/6710#6710) to [Delta printer nozzle not moving square with a perfectly level bed (as if the bed is bent... but it isn't)](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6016/delta-printer-nozzle-not-moving-square-with-a-perfectly-level-bed-as-if-the-bed).