# What options exist for augmenting the automatic bed-leveling?

Tags: bed-leveling, calibration, delta, monoprice-mini-delta

When I print [this file](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2482476), one section smears. The print head is dragged through the soft filament.

At first I thought my aluminum bed was warped, so I upgraded to a glass bed. Test prints were much better, but still had a section that smeared.

My suspicion is that one of the motors needs to be adjusted just enough to balance out the one sector where the print head is too close to the bed. Is there an easier way to calibrate? Is it even possible to do a manual calibration on a per-axis basis on a delta-style printer?

Comment: Like a previous comment mentions about the rarity of Delta questions, could you provide a picture that we can see what is happening?

Comment: `Is it even possible to do a manual calibration on a per-axis basis on a delta-style printer?` - I think this is covered in a very old question: see [my answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/6710/4762) to [Delta printer nozzle not moving square with a perfectly level bed (as if the bed is bent… but it isn't)](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/6016/4762). IIRC, you calibrate each tower in turn, starting at time [13:37](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QuEhQU8vGZk&t=817) in the video. Does that answer your question, or have I mis-understood..?

Comment: I'd love to watch the video, but it is marked as private. :-\  Could you make it available to me?